# Partial declarations of 'WindowsFormsApplication1.frmMain' must not specify different base classes

Tags: c#, winforms, forms

I'm working on WinForm Project.
In the Project I have two Forms frmGeneric and frmMain.
They lile this:

```
namespace WindowsFormsApplication1
{
   public partial class frmGeneric
   {
   }
 }


namespace WindowsFormsApplication1
{
   partial class frmMain:frmGeneric  
   {
   }
}
```

i.e frmMain derives from frmGeneric.

On this row:

```
partial class frmMain:frmGeneric
```

I get this error:

> Partial declarations of 'WindowsFormsApplication1.frmMain' must not specify different base classes    C:...\WindowsFormsApplication1\Form1.Designer.cs

Any Idea why do I get this error and how to fix it?

Comment: What is its base class in `C:...\WindowsFormsApplication1\Form1.Designer.cs`? It is probably just `Form` and you have to specify its base class to be `frmGeneric`

Comment: @HonzaBrestan you should probably post this as an answer.

Comment: Honza Brestan ,please write more more detailed how to implement it?

Comment: Rewritten as an answer with more detailed info - hope it helps.

Comment: Unfortunately, the same olde adage is still valid, even with a RAD tool.  Design first, write code later.  You could have avoided the problem with Project + Add New Item, Windows Forms node, Inherited Form item template.  But that's chicken-and-egg, frmGeneric is the egg.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look inside your `C:...\WindowsFormsApplication1\Form1.Designer.cs` class. It contains another part of `frmMain` class definition and it seems it also has a base class specified and it is another one than your `frmGeneric`.

With partial classes, you either specify the base class only in one part, or it has to be the same base class in the other part(s). Because it still gets compile into one class, you cannot inherit from more than one class.

For the same reason why you cannot have:

```
class Form2 : Form1, Form { ... }
```

you also cannot have:

```
partial class Form2 : Form1 { ... } // File 1
partial class Form2 : Form { ... } // File 2
```

Make sure this is not the case, i.e. (with your class names) either:

```
// File 1 (Form1.cs, probably)
partial class frmMain : frmGeneric { ... }

// File 2 (Form1.designer.cs)
partial class frmMain : frmGeneric { ... }
```

or:

```
// File 1 (Form1.cs, probably)
partial class frmMain : frmGeneric { ... }

// File 2 (Form1.designer.cs)
partial class frmMain { ... }
```